# Ignore non used parameters in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been using different params for different functions that are called from the script externally.

However I noticed that some of functions are failing because its going through all my params instead of the ones I want.

For example, I have a function named `Add-License` that adds a license to a microsoft account. However it only worked when I commented out the other params that aren't needed. Here is the code:

```
param (
    $command,
    $tenantID,
    $appID,
    # $emailresult, #If I don't comment these out, the Add-License function wont work. But I need these all here for other functions.
    # $empw,
    # $emname,
    # $emupn,
    # $emalias,
    # $fname,
    # $lname,
    # $disname,
    $emailaddress,
    $SkuIDresult
    

)

### functions that do other stuff
function Add-License {
    ## Connect to Microsoft Graph Powershell
    $StoreName = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My 
    $StoreLocation = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::CurrentUser
    $Store = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new($StoreName, $StoreLocation) 
    $Flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable
    $Certificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($CertificateFilePath, $pfxPassword, $Flag)
    $Store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
    $Store.Add($Certificate)
    $Store.Close()
    [Convert]::ToBase64String($Certificate.GetRawCertData())
    $Thumbprint = $Certificate.Thumbprint
    Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $appID -TenantId $TenantId -CertificateThumbprint $Thumbprint 
    Set-MgUserLicense -UserId $emailaddress -addlicenses @{SkuId = $SkuIDresult} -RemoveLicenses @() 
    ## Disconnect from Microsoft Graph Powershell
    Disconnect-MgGraph
}
& $command
```

If I **don't** comment out the params, it will fail on the `$emailaddress`

Is there a way I can make a different list of params for each function so they don't get confused?

Thank you for your time,

**UPDATE**: I used @Mathias R. Jessen suggestion to try and add the params to the function itself then call the function. However this didn't work as I can't convert my arguments into a list from the outside.

I am using python to call the powershell module using the subprocess module. Because of this my python code looks something like this:

```
def flow_add_license_to_user_microsoft():
    sqlite_companysearch.company_userselection()
    intermedia_functions.email_selection_only()
    eopappidresult = sqlite_companysearch.comp_searchone.selection_results_eopappid
    onmdomainresult = sqlite_companysearch.comp_searchone.selection_results_onmdomain
    msubresult = sqlite_companysearch.comp_searchone.selection_results_msub
    subprocess.run(["powershell", "microsoft_functions.ps1", "Add-License", onmdomainresult, eopappidresult, intermedia_functions.email_selection_only.email_select, msubresult])
    return
```

So i need `onmdomainresult` `eopappidresult` `intermedia_functions.email_selection_only.email_select` and `msubresult`  to show up as `$tenantID` `$appID` `$emailaddress` `$SkuIDresult` for the subprocess command to powershell. I hope this makes more sense.

I tried using what he said here:

```
param(
  [string]
  $CommandName,

  [System.Collections.IDictionary]
  $Arguments
)

### functions and what not
& $CommandName @Arguments
```

but I got an error saying:

```
microsoft_functions.ps1: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Arguments'. Cannot convert the "jsffinancial2.onmicrosoft.com" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary"
```

Comment: You can use *Parameter Sets* which basically lock in the syntax for that specific parameter set, it's just an attribute you can add to a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you'll want to do is add explicit parameters to `Add-License` instead of relying on variables inherited from the calling scope:

```
function Add-License {
    param(
      [string]$CertificateFilePath,
      [string]$PfxPassword,
      [string]$AppId,
      [string]$TenantId,
      [string]$EmailAddress,
      [guid]$SkuId
    )
    
    ## Connect to Microsoft Graph Powershell
    $StoreName = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My 
    $StoreLocation = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::CurrentUser
    $Store = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new($StoreName, $StoreLocation) 
    $Flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable
    $Certificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($CertificateFilePath, $pfxPassword, $Flag)
    $Store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
    $Store.Add($Certificate)
    $Store.Close()
    [Convert]::ToBase64String($Certificate.GetRawCertData())
    $Thumbprint = $Certificate.Thumbprint
    Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $appID -TenantId $TenantId -CertificateThumbprint $Thumbprint 
    Set-MgUserLicense -UserId $EmailAddress -addlicenses @{SkuId = $SkuID} -RemoveLicenses @() 
    ## Disconnect from Microsoft Graph Powershell
    Disconnect-MgGraph
}
```

Now `Add-License` will no longer be affected by the values of the parameter variables from the script, because a *more local* variable (the parameter we've defined in `Add-License`'s `param()` block) with the same name exists.

Since you want to provide different sets of parameter arguments do different commands dynamically, you might want to consider re-designing your script parameters to take a dictionary/hashtable of arguments instead of individual ones:

```
param(
  [string]
  $CommandName,

  [System.Collections.IDictionary]
  $Arguments
)

# ... function definitions here

& $CommandName @Arguments
```

The `@Arguments` syntax that I'm using here is known as [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) and it will cause PowerShell to pass the dictionary entries as named parameters to the command.

Now you can invoke `Add-Licenses` by calling the script like this:

```
$addLicenseArgs = @{ 
  CertificateFilePath = 'path\to\certfile.pfx'
  PfxPassword         = '<pfx password goes here>'
  AppId               = '<appId>'
  TenantId            = '<tenantId>'
  EmailAddress        = 'username@org.example'
  SkuId               = '<SkuId>' -as [guid]
}

.\script.ps1 -CommandName Add-Licenses -Arguments $addLicenseArgs
```

Which, if we were to invoke `Add-License` directly, would be equivalent to calling:

```
Add-License -CertificateFilePath 'path\to\certfile.pfx' -PfxPassword '<pfx password goes here>' -AppId '<appId>' -TenantId '<tenantId>' -EmailAddress 'username@org.example' -SkuId $('<SkuId>' -as [guid])
```

Comment: I apologize but this is very confusing. I didn't want to have resign everything just for some params to be ignored. Its easier to just make separate files for ever command I need.  I don't know what half these things are. I don't know what `[string]` does or why I need it. I don't understand how to call my function if the params are inside the function instead of at the top. I am not understanding this `@` decorator thingy you have added.  I apologize, I didn't realize this was a lot harder than I thought. I will make different files instead for now.

Comment: @mentalnoob No need to apologize, you haven't done anything wrong :) but it definitely sounds like you're a bit in over your head with trying to write this kind of "framework" code. The better thing would be to package all your functions in a _module_, but you should probably read up on a few things first. I will add some links to the answer tomorrow

Comment: I tried using what you said and it fails on the `[System.Collections.IDictionary]
  $Arguments` section. When I run the code fully it says: `microsoft_functions.ps1: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Arguments'. Cannot convert the "jsffinancial2.onmicrosoft.com" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".` I will update my post to show the work that has been done.

Comment: Now I think I know why this doesn't work. I am using python subprocess module for my external arguments. I am not using powershell to call my microsoft script. This is making more sense why this is not working. I need to use a string, not a dictionary or list to pass the arguments. When It to make a list or dictionary in python of the args it failed. will update the post in a couple of minutes

Comment: @mattias - alright I think I finally figured out my issue and it was super simple. I didn't add the arguments to my subprocess command when trying to call the powershell module through python. When I first made the params, I was able to put in the values without explictly stating which aurgment goes with which value. After I put in the arguments it worked. I will make an answer to my own question but I will prbably give you the answer score I feel your answer helps others more so than my situation. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

So I am going to give the answer to @Mathias as I think his answer will help others better if they ever search this.

However what fixed my issues was to add the actual argument flags in the my subprocess command when I use python to call the powershell module. I also added a `DefaultParameterSetName` to the arguments params.

Here is what my params look like in the script. I didn't put them in the function itself as it wasn't working for me:

```
param (
    $command,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'license')]
    $appID,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'license')]
    $tenantID,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $eoptenantID,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $emailresult,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $empw,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $emname,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $emupn,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $emalias,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $fname,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $lname,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $disname,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'license')]
    $emailaddress,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'license')]
    $SkuIDresult
)
```

Then from my python script I call which ever command I need like this:

```
subprocess.run(["powershell", "microsoft_functions.ps1", 
    "Reset-Email", "-appID", eopappidresult, 
    "-eoptenantID", onmdomainresult, 
    "-empw", intermedia_functions.email_pd.pd, 
    "-emailaddress", intermedia_functions.email_selection_only.email_select])
```